# Trying to create a workflow in vro to trigger an urbancode application process. Client has ucd agent configured

Tags: automation, workflow, vmware, orchestration, urbancode

I am trying to trigger an urbancode application process from a virtual machine spinned up by vrealize orchestrator. Virtual machine is configured with ucd agent.

Explored vrealize orchestrator documentation for creating workflows.

Tried some help from here https://docs.vmware.com/en/vRealize-Orchestrator/7.4/vrealize-orchestrator-74-developers-guide.pdf 
using workflow designer. But failed.

Desired result is workflow should trigger an urbancode application process.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to call the Urbancode REST API to trigger a flow externally. The API is well documented in the [UCD Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4GSP_7.0.2/com.ibm.udeploy.reference.doc/topics/rest_api_ref_overview.html).